# Sending inquiries from "checked" html boxes to email through php

Tags: php, html, sendmail, checkbox

OK, I have googled and googled some more and I am stuck. I am really new to the idea of php but I finally have my form doing what I want, except that when I send it to my email, it only shows one of the boxes that I checked. I really hate asking for help but here goes.

Here is my html:

```
<tr>
 <td valign="left"><p>Please check all items needed *</p>
   <p class="style2">(Default order will be one of each checked item unless otherwise indicated in the comments section.)</p>
 <td valign="top">
     <div align="left">

 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="black_toner" /> Black Toner<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="cyan_toner" /> Cyan Toner<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="magenta_toner" /> Magenta Toner<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="yellow_toner" /> Yellow Toner<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="black_drum" /> Black Drum<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="cyan_drum" /> Cyan Drum<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="magenta_drum" /> Magenta Drum<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="yellow_drum" /> Yellow Drum<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="waste_toner" /> Waste Toner<br />
 <input type="checkbox" name="supplies[]" value="staples" /> Staples<br />
     </div>
   <td valign="top"> </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my php

```
 }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

function clean_string($string) {
  $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
  return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

$email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
$email_message .= "Company: ".clean_string($company)."\n";
$email_message .= "Location: ".clean_string($location)."\n";
$email_message .= "Machine Model: ".clean_string($machine_model)."\n";
$email_message .= "Supplies: ".clean_string($supplies)."\n";
$email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email)."\n";
$email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
$email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  
?>
```

Like I said, I have tried what I think is everything but obviously something is wrong. What do I need to add to my php/html or change to get all of the responses from my checkboxes instead of just one? If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it. (Please be as specific as possible, like I said, I'm a newbie) Thank you!

Comment: $_POST['supplies'] is an array, you need to implode it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show where you're assigning $supplies, but it's an array. Try this when you assign it.

```
$supplies = implode(',',$_POST['supplies']);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

$supplies is an array since you put [] to its form. You have to use the function implode to separate them:

```
$supplies = implode(",", $supplies);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = implode(", " $_POST['supplies']);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/php-checkbox-array-in-form-handling-multiple-checkbox-values-in-an-array.html

1) This HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="1" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="3" />
<input type="checkbox" name="tags[]" value="4" />
```

2) ... becomes this PHP:

```
print_r($_POST['tags']);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

3) In your case, if you checked only "black toner" and "cyan drum" in the form, the only values you should get back in the array are "black_toner" and "cyan_drum".  Just modify your code to process the values you get.

4) I cut/pasted your form, and set the "action=" a script that calls "phpinfo()".  Here are the results from phpinfo, checking only black_toner and cyan_drum:

```
_POST["supplies"]

Array
(
    [0] => black_toner
    [1] => cyan_drum
)
```